# Angular js factory and injecting factory in normal javascript to make it modular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a factory to invoke Rest services using $resource. The factory function is used multiple places in my code and is based on the usage I need to use for different callbacks. I want to create an independent implementation of the implementation of the factory function which I can reuse in other parts of the code.

Following are the required details:

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('UnLockFile', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/files/:fileid/checkin',
            {fileid:'@id'},
            {unlock: {method:'PUT', isArray:false}}    
    );

});
```

**Factory Reuse in other factory (Edited: This is working fine now)**

```
app.factory('FileImplementation', [ 'UnLockFile',
    function(UnLockFile){       

      var FileImplementation= 
      {

          unLockFile : function (userId, fileId, unlockFileCallback) 
          {
                //Create Unlock object
                var unLockFileObj = new UnLockFile({ userid: userId });

                //make server call to lock the file
                unLockFileObj.$unlock({fileid: fileId }, function(response){
                    //invoke callback
                    unlockFileCallback(response);
                });

          }        
      };

      return FileImplementation; 
    }
  ]);
```

**Application code (This is inside Angular scope; using directive):**

```
scope.filemodel = FileImplementation;
scope.filemodel.unLockFile(userId, fileId, unlockFileCallback);
```

Please help.

Comment: hard to make much sense out of this....a concise explanation of the objectives might help

Comment: how can I call factory method outside of angular scope? In angular scope I can inject factory and then I can invoke factory method but how to do outside of angular scope? Hope it clarifies my query.

Comment: I doubt you can, what is use case?

Comment: I want to write these common method one place and then want to use across the application wherever needed. Currently I had to duplicate these methods in each directives which is causing issue to me.

Comment: ok...there's part of what was confusing...you kept saying `outside of angular scope` which sounded like in window global environment. Factory can have as big an object was you need. That object can contain `$resource` as property, but can have other functions, data arrays etc also....does that help?

Comment: helped someone a few days ago with this demo that might help you  http://plnkr.co/edit/68BMEmKYiLN2Vqu8ruWI?p=preview

Comment: I think I can define these common method in top controller and reuse acros application. Will give a try. Thanks for your help.

Comment: look at the 2 controllers in that demo...only one line each....all the other code is in factory and they share same data, methods etc. The displays are identical...which normally wouldn't likely do, but it's the factory useage that is more the point

Comment: This idea to define methods in factory is looking good. I can define all my common method in factory and reuse wherever require by injecting it. Thanks; looks better now.

Comment: this person had 2 controllers with all the same code....so all I really did was move all that code to factory....and one line in each controller did same thing

Comment: Hi Charlie; I tried to use factory however it doesn't seems working. I don't see console error however Rest service call is not working. I have updated code. Please help.

Comment: Hi Charlie, this is working fine now :-) I have edited the post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Charlie's suggestion I have created separate factory having implementation of individual factory operation and then inject this new factory into controller and directives to use it. Posting it to close this question. Following is sample of this factory.

```
app.factory('FileImplementation', [ 'UnLockFile', 'LockFile', 'FileEditSession', function(UnLockFile , LockFile, FileEditSession){      

      var FileImplementation= 
      {

          //Unlock file
          unLockFile : function (userId, fileId, unlockFileCallback) 
          {
                //Create Unlock object
                var unLockFileObj = new UnLockFile({ userid: userId });

                //make server call to lock the file
                unLockFileObj.$unlock({fileid: fileId }, function(response){
                    //invoke callback
                    unlockFileCallback(response);
                });

          }


      };

      return FileImplementation; 
    }
  ]);
```